# Can I raise an exception in `__exit__`?

Tags: python, with-statement

Can I raise exceptions in the `__exit__` method? If so, will this exception be propagated out of a `with` block?

Example:

```
class X:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        raise MyException()


with X() as x:
    pass

// What happens here? Is `MyException` propagated up the stack?
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I currently don't have a python environment here. And even if I tried, I wouldn't know whether it just works by accident but is defined to be undefined behavior. I want to know whether I can safely do this in all cases and all environments.

Comment: You can try it online. There are plenty of online Python environments you can test this kind of thing in. https://ideone.com/, https://repl.it/languages/python3, or https://www.python.org/shell/, for example.

Comment: *"Exceptions that occur during execution of this method will replace any exception that occurred in the body of the `with` statement."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__

Comment: I understand wanting to know whether something is defined behavior (and I'm frequently frustrated when people think that one test that seems to work means that a thing is okay to do). On the other hand, trying it can give a quick answer to a lot of "can I do this" questions when the answer is "no, and there's an obvious error if you try". This doesn't happen to be one of those cases, but that doesn't diminish the utility of trying things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation of [`contextmanager.__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__):

> Exceptions that occur during execution of this method will replace any exception that occurred in the body of the with statement.

And we could see [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for more details. No matter whether **SUITE** throw exception or not, the exception raised by `__exit__` always be throw out to the caller.

```
with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
    SUITE
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
manager = (EXPRESSION)
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)
hit_except = False

try:
    TARGET = value
    SUITE
except:
    hit_except = True
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not hit_except:
        exit(manager, None, None, None)
```